# How to show tasks with deadlines only on their due date?

Tags: org-agenda

Here is what I mean:

[image]

The task with a deadline is displayed more than once in the agenda, which confuses me. How can I show this task in my agenda only once, under its due date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [`(org) Deadlines and scheduling`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html):

```
On the deadline date, the task is listed in the agenda.  In
addition, the agenda for _today_ carries a warning about the
approaching or missed deadline, starting
‘org-deadline-warning-days’ before the due date, and continuing
until the entry is marked DONE.
```

So:

> How can I show this task in my agenda only once, under its due date?

Customise `org-deadline-warning-days`:

```el
(setq org-deadline-warning-days 0)
```

the documentation of which user option reads:

```
org-deadline-warning-days is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is 14

Documentation:
Number of days before expiration during which a deadline becomes active.
This variable governs the display in sparse trees and in the agenda.
When 0 or negative, it means use this number (the absolute value of it)
even if a deadline has a different individual lead time specified.

Custom commands can set this variable in the options section.
```